# how to make a dynamic three dimensional array where only the first dimension is the dynamic one in c

Tags: c, dynamic, multidimensional-array, malloc, realloc

i have a three dimensional bit table array as

`bit_table[dim1][100][200];`

The second and third dimensions are always the same.

But **dim1** have to grow with time.

when this **bit_table** is full its size need to grow in the **dim1** dimension and the **old content needs to be retained**

To retain the old content of the table, should i just create a temporary array, copy the old array data to it, and, after the array is expanded, copy back this data? Or is there a better way to do it?

EDIT:

```
int dim1=10;
unsigned char (*bit_table)[100][200] = (unsigned char)malloc(dim1 * sizeof(*bit_table));
printf("enter new dimension\n");
     scanf(dim1);
```

....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int (*bit_table)[100][200] = malloc(dim1 * sizeof(*bit_table));

...

bit_table = realloc(bit_table, dim1_new * sizeof(*bit_table));

...

free(bit_table);
```

Obviously, you will need appropriate error-handling for both of these calls.  In particular, if `realloc` fails (in the above code) then you will end up with a memory leak.

Comment: i am using vc2010 and i am stuck trying to typecast the void type of malloc to unsigned char. Please see my edit

Comment: @John: why would you do that? `bit_table` has type `unsigned char (*)[100][200]`, not `unsigned char`; also, casting the return value of `malloc()` is unnecessary in C; if you're using C++, why aren't you using a `vector`?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but I didn't see any special difficulty here. Besides the `realloc` as Charlesworth mentioned. You can also:

```
typedef unsigned char bit_table_elem[100][200];

// if you're using c, linked list will be a good choice
// but if you really need indexing, then use the realloc way...
struct bit_table_list {
    bit_table_elem elem;
    struct bit_table_list* next;
}

// if you're using c++, std vector will be better
std::vector<bit_table_elem> bit_table
```

Comment: A linked-list might be good for arbitrary changes in size, but it's bad for array-style access.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, that's why I put the comment" if you need indexing, then use the realloc way".